# How to run .asp net web application on a host?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I know this is an absolute newbie question but I honestly couldn't figure it out, I'm totally new to .ASP .NET so excuse me.

I've published my web app through an FTP connection and it's uploaded on an .asp [hosting service](https://www.smarterasp.net/).
Now how can I run the website? For running it on a localhost I need to run the webapp.exe file then I'm able to see it through the link, but I clearly cannot run the .exe file on the host service, how can I see the output? there's no .asp file, only thing is an index.html in /ClientApp which doesn't work either.

(PS. it uses Angular as frontend)

Comment: Are you on Windows server?

Comment: Yes, I linked the host service, it's a windows server hosting

Comment: I dont know the service but you should create/start an application pool on the IIS server. Copy all your files into its working directory and then you should have some domain pointing to this location and when you visit it via browser your Index.html should display by default

Comment: Oh, then for a web app to run you need to deploy it on an IIS not just a windows hosting server?

Comment: I just simply want to upload my website and publish it, how can I get an .asp or index.html output that works, idk why but it's really confusing.

Comment: Check with your hosting provider on how to create an AppPool (IIS should already be on Windows). When it is created/setup you have to publish your website to it's working (www) directory.

Comment: If you have full access to your Windows (virtual?) server then just follow these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/

Comment: Is there any error message that you see? Have you contacted your hosting provider?